# What is the correct Latin prefix for 'two-and-a-half-times'?

Tags: vocabulary, prefix, mathematics, numbers

**Question.**

What is the latin prefix for "2½ times" ?

**Remark.**

- The question asks for the correct analogue of the prefix "sesqui-" which, of course, is the prefix for "1½ times".

Comment: There is a decent chance that there is no such prefix at all. After all, we are extremely unlikely to have a separate prefix for 13½ times or the like, so the prefix sequence (*semi-*, *sesqui-*, ...) has to terminate somewhere. Whether 2½ is included is a good question.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. There was a precise motivation for this: it can be *useful*, to give structure to investigations, to have words for the *number of syllables in (the usual spoken rendition of) a word*, and yes, **half-syllables** [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_syllable) [on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquisyllabic)  the radar of science, and yet I do not know of any usual term for 2½-syllabic. In particular "sestersyllabic" is (probably not for long because of this thread) currently an example of the rare species of reasonable words with **0** hits on G.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very common word in Latin that literally means "two and a half": [***sestertium, -i***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsestertius). This comes from [*semis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsemis) + *tertius*, the idea being (I suppose) that it is "half-way to three [from two]."

This usage is antiquated and almost entirely replaced by the current meaning of a "serterce," which according to L&S is:

> a small silver coin, originally equal to **two and a half asses**

L&S also quotes *sestertium* as meaning "two and a half feet [deep]," as used by [Columella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columella) in *De Arboribus*:

> ipsum agrum sat erit bipalio vertere: quod vocant rustici sestertium. (1)

...but this seems like sloppy research to me, since the sentence that immediately follows suggests a number more like 1 2/3:

> ...Ea repastinatio altitudinis habet plus sesquipedem, minus tamen quam duos pedes.

If you wish to use a prefix for "two and a half" then, you could feasibly go with ***sester-***. It turns out that this phrase already has some traction, for instance as applied to a 250 year anniversary: "sestercentennial". See, for example, this [*New York Times* article](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/12/13/magazine/on-language-by-william-safire-woodshed-blues-kimble-mead.html?pagewanted=all), this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary), and [~28K Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=sestercentennial). These are all decidedly non-authoritative.

### Alternatives

The above-cited Wikipedia article offers one other alternative that fits this case: **semiquin-**, which means "half of five."

### A Word of Caution

The ultimate answer to your question is that **there is no frequently used, easily understood** prefix for "two and a half." This is probably because (!) it's not a terribly useful thing to have.

Classical attestations of any of the above suggestions are conspicuously absent, whereas we have from Varro a very clean example of what a Roman might have done when faced with the same question. Does he use "sesterpedis" to refer to a two-and-a-half-foot distance? Let's look:

> ...tympanum in latitudinem **duo pedes et semipedem**, in altitudinem palmum. (Varro, *Res Rusticae* 3.5.15.5)

So much easier to understand!

Comment: +1 for completeness

Comment: Many thanks for this. For motivation, see my comment under the OP. Do you agree that, when used with care, **sestersyllabic** is a reasonable coinage? ("semiquinsyllabic" seems not as good, both because first going to 5 and the halving is an overcomplication, and because it is longer.)

Comment: @guest I suppose it is reasonable. Out of curiosity, what could you possibly be referring to? Isn't syllable count discrete?

Comment: @brianpck: for 1½ times this is already [in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquisyllabic) [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_syllable), and I need to use it for words with 2½ syllables.

Comment: For what it's worth, _sesqui-_ and the other prefixes are literal and additive ("½ and a ~") so _sester-_ would more likely be something like "½ less than 3" in the manner of Latin's 18 and 19 rather than "half the distance from 2 to 3".

Comment: Personally, I think the answer would benefit from avoiding the commentary on the appropriateness of the question. OP already gave their (admittedly bizarre) usage case and the "so much easier" version is (of course) to _just use English_. English only needs Latin precisely for these prefixed versions.

Comment: This question has come up in the context of wanting an "X-centennial" word for the upcoming 250th anniversary of United States independence.  It seems that the official term is "semiquincentennial", but that just seems sesquipedalian to me.

Answer (score 3):

The answer could be 'hemipenta' (half of five) as in hemipentahydrate meaning 5 water molecules of crystallization per two molecules of compound. This is cumbersome and probably Greek rather than Latin root per se, but seems it is the related term to Monohydrate 1 water per molecule, Sesquihydrate 3 waters per two molecules, Dihydrate 2 waters per molecule and Trihydrate 3 waters per molecule. Anyway it appears to be in current chemical use for the hydration ratio of 5:2.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for the post. It is Greek indeed, but it's still good information to have.

Answer (score 0):

A table of numercal prefixes is given in *Wikipedia*; both cardinal & multiple forms. What we are duscussing here is the *muliple* form. Perhaps surprisingly, there is one for 1¼, which is *quasqui*. So perhaps one could use *biquasqui* for the 2½ multiple prefix.

But as for *sester*, I've also read of that one - I can't remember where now; but whatever the writing was that said it, it simply said without qualifcation it *is* the prefix, whereas a previous respondent *speculates* that it *might* be admissible. However, it is **not** in the *Wikipedia* table. I *do* use it and am going to continue to do so, anyway!

The previous respondent also says it's use-potential is *borderline* (not verbatim). As I said, I do use it; and I find that opportunities for doing so are not **extremely** rare. As for *sestercentenial*: an alternative there, as in the same table *quater* is given for the  ¼ multiple prefix, would be *quatermillenial*.

There is perhaps no precedent for concatenation of *bi* & another prefix ... but concatenenation of it with **any** other of these *multiple* prefixes known to me would result in an elementary redundancy. It does so even in the case of *quasqui* if *sester* be admitted. And given *quater*, the concatenation *hemisemi*, as in *hemisemiquaver* in music, is similarly a redundancy.

As for the idea of 'half a syllable': I think that arises in connection with a word such as 'Popocatapetl', or 'Lyublyana': in the case of the former, a native Mexican will pronounce the '-etl' at the end as a single syllable, whereas an English speaker tends to make *two* syllables of it, but with some effort might be able to get it *close* to being a single syllable - perhaps a *sesquisyllable*; and likewise in the latter case - that of a native *Slavonic* speaker, & the 'Lyu-' & '-lya-' in 'Lyublyana'.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you happen to have any examples of *bi-* being actually used to multiply a prefix, as in *biquasqui-*? I'm not sure that would be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Yeah, no. _quasqui-_ isn't multiplictive. It's additive: ¼ _and a_ ~. The equivalent format would be _quasquibi-_, not _biquasqui-_.